# jQuery to get data from the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hashtag

## I'm trying to get jQuery to take the hashtag from a URL and do some functions with it:

Hashtag example:

```
http://www.example.com/Help.asp#contact
```

I built out a help center. This help center hides all the answers on the page load and when you click on a question, the answer slides down. Each question is it's own `anchor` with a name identifier. So when you go to http://www.example.com/Help.asp#contact, the document automatically scrolls down to `<a name="contact">`. We use these a lot in emails or whatever when we want to direct a user **straight** to the question they're asking in the Help Center. However, it would be even easier to use, if that `anchor` is triggered a second after the page loads. What I'm guessing is, I'd need to grab the hashtag, and have a jQuery script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[name="~~HASHTAG~~"]').trigger('click').delay(1000);
});
```

How can I get the hashtag from the URL? Thanks for your help.

Here's my HTML http://jsfiddle.net/tBLuL/

Comment: `alert(location.hash.replace("#", ""))`

Comment: So how do I append that value to the name=""

Comment: `$('a[name="'+location.hash.replace("#", "")+'"]')` but you should check at first that it exists, otherwise it might select all `a`'s or none - test it :)

Comment: @Cheery add as an answer and I'll accept

Comment: I do not care about points - I'm here to help :) Thanks anyway and choose between given answers.

Comment: cheery, its not for you to have points. it will make it lot easier for others to zero in on correct answer.

Comment: @Cheery Okay, if that's what you want... Question, does it have to be on the document ready? If I'm already on the page, and add #contact to the URL, the page won't reload and the jQuery won't execute

Comment: @Tejas the correct answer already exists, even being written slightly after my comment here. That is why I do not want to write another one and asked to choose between existing answers.

Comment: @user1090389  `does it have to be on the document ready?` on document ready you can be sure that `a` tag with required name is already loaded. You may call it just placing the js code without document ready before the `</body>` tag.  `and add #contact to the URL` do you add it manually? In this case, of course, page is not reloaded. If you 'add' by clicking on the link then you have to add event listener in the links with hashes and call your code on clicks.

Comment: @user1090389  Let me make it clear. Code in document ready and at the bottom of the page is called only once, when the page is actually loading. If you change hash manually or by clicking on the hash links at the same page, the page is not loaded. In that case you have to run your code at clicks on the links.

Comment: @Cheery It isn't the most important thing. If I need it, I'll post another question but it isn't exactly necessary.

Comment: @user1090389  Could you state it clearly what do you want? The code that you were talking before is related to the page opened in the browser with some hash in the URL. What else do you want? To be able to change the hash manually and to open automatically the field on the page related to a new hash?

Comment: No, if you click on a link `<a href="#hashtag">` in the page, the page isn't reloaded, so therefore the jQuery doesn't execute. Should I position the jQuery differently for it to execute even during in session events?

Comment: @user1090389   But in that case you do not need to work with the hash. As I can see from your example at jsfiddle - you open the text of the answer directly. That is I wondering what is wrong. In general you need two parts - one of them takes hash part of the URL after load and opens corresponding answer. Another is dealing with the clicks on the same page.  Sorry for the delay, mention by `@nickname`, so that I could see the response as soon as it is posted.

Comment: Sorry @Cheery forgot about that. I'm talking about a solution that works both ways, with the hash and with inline links that are not the question, a separate link on the page. Honestly, I don't need it right now, maybe I will in the future, so that's why I was asking about it, but I was thinking, even when the page is not being loaded, when you're in the page already, adding the hash should not only jump to the anchor, but it should also expand the answer. But it isn't really all that important. Plus, if I wanted to use anchors with the hash, I could also add onclick trigger the other element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('a[name="' + location.hash.replace('#', '') + '"]').click().delay(1000);
```

The delay of 1 sec after the click is useless. What are you trying to achieve with delay?

**Update:**

If you want to delay the `click` try this.

```
$('a[name="' + location.hash.replace('#', '') + '"]').delay(1000).click();
```

Comment: That will not delay the `click`. The `click` has already triggered. Instead call `delay` first and then trigger the `click` event.

Comment: You mean the `delay` or the `click`?

Comment: I generally don't prefer using `delay` but use `setTimeout`. You can try this `setTimeout(function(){ $('a[name="' + location.hash.replace('#', '') + '"]').click(); }, 1000);`

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the javascript value

```
location.hash
```

It will contain the #Hash part of the url, in your case

```
#contact
```

Comment: So how do I append that value to the name=""

Comment: Xander beat me to it.  Like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `hash` property off of the `window` object ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var thehash = window.location.hash; // #contact

    $('a[name="' + thehash.replace('#','') + '"]')
                         .trigger('click')
                         .delay(1000);
});
```

Comment: So how do I append that value to the name=""

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) object. `location.hash` has exactly what you're looking for, no jQuery required.